# Visual Studio 2019 - Git Source Control: How to enable visual comparison mark of commits in "Manage Branches" Window?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I use Visual Studio 2019. In the Manage Branches window there was a feature, very useful I think, through which the Git Repository pointed with a red mark those commits from the browsed branch that matched with any HEAD from local branches. To explain myself I attach an image. The marks I'm asking about are those I enclosed with a green rounded rectangle.

[image: Git Repository Window]

These marks are useful because they tell me which local branches I had already pushed to remote, just browsing remote branches. This way I could realize which local branches aren't needed already in my workspace.

Some time ago I noted that those marks disappeared, they really do things faster when I clean my workspace because now I must take note of all local branches HEAD hashes and compare them with the remote branch I am browsing.

My question is ¿How do I enable this feature in Visual Studio? or ¿Is it something that is disabled in Git configuration?

I copied the image from [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-browse-repository?view=vs-2019). I can't take an image from my UI because currently the marks I ask about are not rendered in my UI.

Greetings and thanks to whoever can collaborate me with his/her valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to post my question on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/vs-general.html) platform it suggested me to review this Question [What does master tag mean in history for Git in Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444906/what-does-master-tag-mean-in-history-for-git-in-visual-studio-2019). Reading the answer posted by [Chad B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1724261/chad-b) I found the answer to my question too.

The Graph View, the same view that UI displays for "Branch History" on de right panel of "Git Repository" (the one displayed when you click "Manage Branches" option) has 2 buttons above to manage which set of branches show marked with the red tag I was asking for. The buttons are:
[image]

As Chad B explains:

> "The toolbar in the History window has three buttons on it where you
> can toggle seeing local branches, remote tracking branches, and tags
> labeled onto the corresponding commits. By default, branches are
> rendered red and tags are green. Hovering the mouse over the label
> should also tell you if it's a branch or tag."

For this question I should use "Show Local Branches" button